# Updating UITableView within UICollectionViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionViewCell containing some buttons, label and a UITableView. This table view varies in number of rows and content. The UICollectionViewCell is the table views data source and delegate.
UICollectionViewController forces me to use `[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellID" forIndexPath:indexPath]`.

When scrolling through the UICollectionView the UITableView within the UICollectionViewCell doesn't update its content.

Calling `[tableview reloadData]` doesn't affect the number of rows.
Calling UICollectionViews `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths` seems to be no good choice for performance.

Does anybody know a more clever way to update the table view inside the collection view cell instead of reusing previous cells' table views?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the delegate properly? If reloaddata is not updating the number of rows, there might be a problem with the delegate settings.